# Novel about a headteacher who's a red ant

Tags: story-identification

This would be from the early 80's most likely, possibly the late 70's. What I remember about the novel was that it was basically a '*Kids vs. Adults*' sort of thing, took place in a school and the headmaster was a Red Ant. If the red ant bit you, you froze...

This is seriously all I can remember as I was fairly young when I read it, hopefully this rings a bell to someone on here?

If it's any help, I think I read this around the same time as another book called '*Ace Hits the Big Time*' which was published in 1981.

Comment: Was this a novel or a short story? How was the head a red ant. Was he in disguise or did everyone know about it? Was there only one ant or many? Who were the kids? What were their names/ages/genders?

Comment: You might want to have a read through [How to ask a good story-ID question?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see if the checklists can jog any memories.

Comment: Sorry I am a noob here... I will do some more research!  :)This was a novel, I believe the head was an actual red ant, but it might have been that the main character was just believing that or projecting it or something? Sorry, that's all I got..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the book *[The War Between the Pitiful Teachers and the Splendid Kids](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?576474)* by Stanley Kiesel.

The red ant is Mr. Foreclosure, a mutation born to human parents. He has an unusually large head, but is otherwise a red ant.

Comment: OMG! Yes that's it, I can't believe I got an answer after over 3 years!!! Thanks!!!!